# Parse: How to know whether a image file has been cached using PFImageView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, caching, parse-platform

I am using iOS Parse and I want to know whether a image has been cached to make decision on some animation.

Any good idea? I am very appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

PFImageView.file.dataAvailable should work.